# Що означає слово "добінька"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники, діалектизми

Випадково почула розмову жіночок, одна з яких розповідала про те, що в чоловіка зламалася добінька, треба її або відремонтувати, або купити нову.

Звернулася у **[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/dobinjka)**, а там такого слова немає. Тоді заглянула в Інтернет-простір, знайшла лише працю Василя Сокола **[“Матеріали до фольклористичної експедиції”](http://nz.ethnology.lviv.ua/archiv/2016-3/11.pdf)**, в якій згадується це слово, однак у такому значенні:

> **добінька** - маленьке недорозвинене куряче яйце.

Очевидно, що до ілюстрованого мною контексту це значення не підходить. То що ж означає слово ***добінька***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скоріш за все **добінька** -це [молот](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53396/264093.html). Знаходимо подібне слово і в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/dovbenjka):

> **ДОВБЕ́НЬКА**, їй ж. Зменш.-пестл. до **довбня** 1. Микула взяв свою рушницю, шаблю і довбеньку, якій більш вірив, ніж зброї.

За відсиланням знаходимо:

> **ДО́ВБНЯ,** і, жін.
>
> 1. Великий, перев. дерев'яний молот або взагалі велика дерев'яна палиця з потовщенням на кінці. Де ще те теля, а він уже з довбнею бігає! (Українські народні прислів'я та приказки, 1955, 176)...

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/dovbnja).

Очевидно, що в різних діалектах це слово має різні забарвлення, звідси і **добінька**.